# Загружать контент по имен запроса на PHP

Tags: php, маршрутизация, route

**Доброго времени суток!
Хочу реализовать задачу но не знаю как!**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект состоит из следующих файлов и папок.
Мне нужно чтобы при написании запроса типа [www.example.com/region1](http://www.example.com/region1) или [www.example.com/region17](http://www.example.com/region17) url адрес страницы остался таким же как написали и на этой страницы должны загружаться все содержимое папки content_regions

Папка content_regions имеет следующие файлы (index,about,contact,news)

Как реализовать это?

Comment: region1  и region17  - уже не верно. т.к. нет (есть, но идеологически не верные) указатели для возможности написания корректного маршрутизатора.  Как правило есть слэш, для разделения частей. то есть должно быть region/1  и region/17

Comment: спасибо. Но в основном эти регионы могут быт типа : moskow, kazan, dushanbe и тп

Comment: А не проще ли будет хранить данные для регионов в БД, и динамически получать их из базы, используя только 4 файла страниц? Так можно избавиться от дублирования кучи файлов